# Joomla - two (main)content modules have a max width

Tags: css, templates, uikit, joomla3.0, joomla-module

I am making a template to a website, and have a final problem that I can't solve.
Two of the pages ("Bliv medlem" and "Kontakt DJK") seems to have a max width to the (main)content module. The only thing I've coded is the UI-kit "uk-width-1-1@s uk-width-4-5@m" classes. I have looked at all the classes and attributes I could see affected the modules, but I haven't been able to find anything.

On the page "Bliv medlem" the div tag containing the "content" module seems to have a max size of 1203.980 px. On the page "Kontakt DJK" the same module seems to have a max size of 891.656 px.

The website I'm making a template for is http://djk.limfjordsbanen.dk/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=8&Itemid=103&lang=da (at the moment only in Danish).

I am using the 3.9.16 version of Joomla and UIkit version 3.0.0-rc.2.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason is because of the actual content you have on some of the pages.

If you have full-width paragraph text on http://djk.limfjordsbanen.dk/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=20&Itemid=128&lang=da you'll see that the 'content' module is wider (please see attachment 1)

[image]

Or alternatively, if you CSS hide the unordered list on http://djk.limfjordsbanen.dk/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=4&Itemid=112&lang=da the width of the 'content' module decreases. (please see attachment #2)

[image]

Good luck, I hope this helps!